# SRC sharing on facebook using asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net, sql

I have one I frame to play videos.

```
<iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/81348723" id ="centralImage"  width="840" height="400" ></iframe>
```

Here I need to transfer I frame SRC to href in the place of google example:

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=//player.vimeo.com/video/81348724" target="_blank">
```

This is my sharing buttons. Actually, I need to share the current SRC link of I frame to Facebook.

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/share?text=An%20Awesome%20Link&url=http://www.google.com" target="_blank"><img src="image/twitter.gif"width="30" height="30" > </a>
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://www.google.com" target="_blank"><img src="image/facebook.gif" width="30" height="30"></a>
```

This is my repeater code for when user to click the image then image URL will transfer to I Frame SRC and video will play.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that once the location of the iframe has left your domain/original address, you cannot access the 'current' location.

You also cannot access the dom of the document in the iframe.

The only thing you can really do is try and pull in the body of the external site and render it in a div (then try and hi-jack user clicks to get the location) but this is very site specific and probably won't be viable for what you're trying to do.

Comment: Had you understood my question. @hairmot